# How to install clang pre-built binaries ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, llvm

I am very new to linux, and don't know where I need to put Clang pre-built binaries http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.3  .  I download it, unpack with mouse, and add path to /bin to my $PATH, and path to /lib to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and add *.conf with path to my /lib to /etc/ld.so.conf.d . I even reboot my notebook.
...but still cant build my simple program with Code::Blocks GCC (error: /home/aadgrand/tmp/LLVM-3.3/final/llvm.src/lib/Support/Signals.cpp - undefined reference to `dladdr'). 
Text of the test programm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    llvm::LLVMContext &c = llvm::getGlobalContext(); // error line
    cout << "Never printed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What else I need to do? Maybe I need to use *.sig-file? Hm?

Same question as [How to install CLang using precompiled binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045954/how-to-install-clang-using-precompiled-binaries) . 
Sorry for repeat, but it is really very interesting and important.

===== UPDATED ======

I've just insalled llvm-3.1, same error like with llvm-3.4 (from pre-built binaries):

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test2 ---------------

Compiling: main.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++98' '-pg' '-g' '-v' '-Wall' '-fexceptions' '-I' '/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include' '-c' '-o' 'obj/Debug/main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE /home/kpdev/projects/test2/test2/main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip obj/Debug/main.o -g -Wall -std=c++98 -version -p -fexceptions -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccbKoBDJ.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.6
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 65b5171ac1bd7b3f07dbea6bdb24be3d
/home/kpdev/projects/test2/test2/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/kpdev/projects/test2/test2/main.cpp:11:24: warning: unused variable ‘c’ [-Wunused-variable]
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++98' '-pg' '-g' '-v' '-Wall' '-fexceptions' '-I' '/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include' '-c' '-o' 'obj/Debug/main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as --64 -o obj/Debug/main.o /tmp/ccbKoBDJ.s
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++98' '-pg' '-g' '-v' '-Wall' '-fexceptions' '-I' '/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/include' '-c' '-o' 'obj/Debug/main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'



Linking console executable: bin/Debug/test2
/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `dladdr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
2 errors, 1 warnings


||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Are you able to build and run "Hello World" with your clang 3.3 installation under Code::Blocks?

Comment: I can compile my example manually with clang++ and terminal. But in C::B it is so troublesome...

Comment: Can you copy and post the contents of C::B's Build Log tab after you have unsuccessfully tried to build your prog?

Comment: Yes, of course ) See update of the question

Comment: Hm... There is no any `llvm` folder in `LIBRARY_PATH` - is it normal?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The title of your question has misled both myself and Atropo. It looked as if
you want to install the *clang C++ compiler* and build an llvm
C++ program with it in Code::Blocks.

What you are actually trying to do is install clang+llvm (they are actually
different things) and build an llvm program with *GCC* in Code::blocks.
You did say "Code::Blocks GCC", but I assumed that just meant
"I had Code::Blocks set up with GCC and now I want to use clang". The C::B build log
that you have added, however, shows that you *building* with GCC.

Given that you are building your llvm program with GCC it is not clear why
you want to install the clang compiler. Perhaps you want to use clang but you
do not know that Code::Blocks can support the clang compiler, or do not know how to
configure C::B to use clang. But let's take one thing at time. You *can* build
this llvm program with gcc if you just get things set up properly. *And* -
a separate issue - you can install clang properly. And
- another separate issue - you can configure C::B to build with clang if you want.

Atropo pasted commands for installing the latest 
clang and its debugger lldb. But clang doesn't need all the llvm libraries and 
installing just clang and lldb does not give you all the libraries you need to 
build your llvm program.

You said in one of your comments that you had been able to build your program
with clang++ in a terminal. That suggests you had, at that point, a working
manual install of clang and llvm. But I don't know if you still have one after
the intervening messing about and anyway I agree with Atropo that manually
installing such complex software - customizing your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
etc. etc. - is much less sensible than a managed installation from a package
repoository, letting the package manager get things right.

First, let's build your llvm program with gcc in C::B, and for that, begin with some
precautionary steps that may or may not be necessary:

- Undo all that customizing you did and delete or conceal your manually
  installed clang/llvm binaries.
- Get all your packages up to date. In a console, run:

  `sudo apt-get update`
- Ensure you have all the basic packages for building C/C++ software. In the
  console, run:

  `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

That finishes the precautions. Next:

- Install llvm from the standard ubuntu 12.04 repository. You'll get an old
  one, v2.9 but that's fine for now:

  `sudo apt-get install llvm`

Now you've got all the software you need. Keep that console handy and launch
C::B in your simple llvm project.

- As you now have a standard system-install of llvm, change the second two
  `#include` directives of your source code to the following:

  `#include <llvm/Module.h>`

  `#include <llvm/LLVMContext.h>`
- Get llvm to tell you what compiler options you need to pass to GCC. In the
  console run:

  `llvm-config --cxxflags`
- Copy the output of that command from the console to the clipboard. In C::B,
  open your project's *Build options* and navigate *Compiler settings* -> *Other options*
  for GCC. In the *Other options* edit-box, paste in the compiler options from
  the clipboard and OK it.
- Get llvm to tell you what libraries you need to link. In the
  console run:

  `llvm-config --libs`
- Copy the output of that command from the console to the clipboard (this time 
  there is a lot of it). In C::B, navigate *Build options* -> *Linker settings* -> *Other linker options*.
  In the edit-box, paste in the library options from the clipboard and OK it.
- Get llvm to tell you what (other) options you need to pass to the linker. In the
  console run:

  `llvm-config --ldflags`
- Copy the output of that command from the console to the clipboard. In C::B,
  navigate, once again, *Build options* -> *Linker settings* -> *Other linker options*
  In the edit-box, *after* - repeat, *after* - the library options you have previously pasted there,
  paste in the additional linker options from the clipboard and OK it.
- Now rebuild your project and this time it will compile and link with only
  only a warning for the unused variable `c` (at least it does for me).

That covers building your program. If you now run it, it will output "Never printed",
which I guess you don't want it to; but that's a problem for you :) It builds and runs.

If you also want to install all the latest llvm and clang packages, read on.

- Install the llvm toolchain repository, for Ubuntu 12.04, in your software sources

  `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise main'`
- Install the gpg key of that repository to authenticate package downloads from it. *Note
  the final hyphen on this commandline*:

  `wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -`
- Refresh your package database again:

  `sudo apt-get update`
- Install the whole llvm+clang toolchain:

  `sudo apt-get install clang-3.4 clang-3.4-doc libclang-common-3.4-dev libclang-3.4-dev libclang1-3.4 libclang1-3.4-dbg libllvm-3.4-ocaml-dev libllvm3.4 libllvm3.4-dbg lldb-3.4 llvm-3.4 llvm-3.4-dev llvm-3.4-doc llvm-3.4-examples llvm-3.4-runtime cpp11-migrate-3.4 clang-format-3.4`
- Prove that you have got clang 3.4:

  `clang -v`

This command should output:

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1~exp1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Finally, you might want to configure C::B to use clang instead of GCC. I will
just get you started.

- In C::B, navigate to *Compiler settings* for GCC and click the *Copy* button.
  In the *Add new compiler* edit-box, enter `clang-3.4` and click OK. Then
  follow the prompt that C::B gives you to *update the "Toolchain executables" page*.

Comment: Thank you! It works! You did great job for me and horde of ubuntu-newbies. This is an excellent step-by-step guide. You a great man, really )

Comment: Very glad to have helped. You had clearly been giving it a fight.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. I've been trying to compile LLVM via the command line on Ubuntu 12.04 and this is the ONLY answer I've found anywhere on the internet that solves the problem while giving a great explanation of what everything does. Thank you very much @MikeKinghan

Answer (score 5):

Instead of manually install it you can use the `LLVM` repo, add it to your `apt` sources and install it via `apt-get` or the Ubuntu packet manager. See [LLVM apt repo](http://llvm.org/apt/) on how to do it.

Do the steps as written in the *Install* paragraph, in a terminal:

```
sudo wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install clang-3.4 lldb-3.4
```

Comment: Ubuntu:     
deb http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise main.        
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise main.
Should I print it in terminal? deb command not found :(

Comment: Something wrong... `E: Unable to locate package clang-3.4`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'clang-3.4'`
`E: Unable to locate package lldb-3.4`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lldb-3.4`'

Comment: If I type `sudo apt-get install clang` , it return me `The following extra packages will be installed:
  libclang-common-dev libffi-dev llvm-3.0 llvm-3.0-dev llvm-3.0-runtime Suggested packages: llvm-3.0-doc The following NEW packages will be installed: clang libclang-common-dev libffi-dev llvm-3.0 llvm-3.0-dev llvm-3.0-runtime 0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` so, why it don't see clang-3.4 ?

Comment: Looks like the package is named `clang` you can see the info about the package (like the version) with `sudo apt-cache show clang`.

Comment: it give me for install clang-3.5! Why? it is currently development branch, I use stable.

Comment: According to the askubuntu site that is purely the name that is showing 3.5 the actual command when run with `-v` should show 3.6

Comment: I'm having problems using the symbolic links shown in the answer - http://askubuntu.com/questions/584711/clang-and-clang-not-found-after-installing-the-clang-3-5-package