# install llvm-3.4 on ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: installation, clang, ubuntu-12.04, llvm, lldb

I already read these threads:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/309786/llvm-and-clang-installation-on-ubuntu
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/309473/install-clang-3-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-see-unmet-dependencies-errors

but none of them helped me, because my problem is a Little bit different.

When I run `sudo apt-get install llvm-3.4 libclang1-3.4 llvm-3.4-dev` I get this output:

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
libclang1-3.4 ist schon die neueste Version.
libclang1-3.4 wurde als manuell installiert festgelegt.
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
llvm-3.4 : Hängt ab von: libclang1 (>= 1:3.4~svn193671-1~exp1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

Sorry that it's german... but it says that libclang1-3.4 is already the newest Version and manually installed, and that llvm-3.4 depends on libclang1 (>= 1:3.4) which should not be installed, and that I have Held broken packages.

I really don't know what to do.

I want to install Version 3.4 because I want to work with the lldb which is part of the 3.4 package.

Comment: You can read answer to question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657261/how-to-install-clang-pre-built-binaries-ubuntu-12-04
it might be useful

Comment: The current release of LLVM is 3.3. LLVM 3.4 has not been released; it should be released in December 2014.

Comment: @MarshallClow: I followed the steps outlined at this page: http://llvm.org/apt/. And under **Install** everything has this dubious `3.4`. That's why I tried to install Version 3.4.

Comment: @Rico-E - those are nightly builds. That's perfectly fine to use, but you should be aware that it is changing _every day_. It may contain bugs that were not there yesterday, and may be gone tomorrow.

Comment: @MarshallClow: I'm fine with that, but it doesn't help me to install this.

Answer (score 1):

At first update your repository with

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the dependent package as

```
$ sudo apt-get install libclang1
```

Also try with

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

then install the required package.
It is basically a package dependency problem. Try finding how to remove/install package dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. After I did all the steps, I still get the Output, that llvm-3.4 has unmet dependencies with libclang1 (>=1:3.4).

Comment: just check out this link & try with it.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/126474/how-to-solve-apt-package-cannot-be-configured-because-package-is-in-a-different