# How to install CLang 5 after downloading .tar.xz file from llvm.org

Tags: linux, tar, llvm-clang

I downloaded clang+llvm-5.0.0-linux-x86_64-ubuntu16.04.tar.xz from llvm.org

Then, I expanded the archive into a folder on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit machine. The contents of the expanded folder look like this:

```
$ ls clang+llvm-5.0.0-linux-x86_64-ubuntu16.04.tar.xz
```

bin  docs  include  lib  share

Question: What do I do next? Do I have to copy these into some folders myself, and if so, which ones exactly?

There is a link to this answer but I'm not able to understand it at all.

[How to install CLang using precompiled binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045954/how-to-install-clang-using-precompiled-binaries)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've downloaded version 15.0.6, for example, and your filename resembles `clang+llvm-15.0.6-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz` then a couple more steps are needed.

You will need XZ decompression binaries and a compatible `tar` CLI which supports decompression using it (otherwise operate them on multiple successive commands by first decompressing then unwinding the tape archive).

The command to do this is: `tar -x --xz --strip-components=1 -f clang+llvm-15.0.6-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz`

You should see these directories:

```
# Assume this is at /home/user/.local/llvm-15
.
├── bin
├── include
├── lib
├── libexec
└── share
```

Now any Clang++ invocations you'll make will require `-I /home/user/.local/llvm-15`. For example:

```
clang++ -c -o ./some_llvm_ext.o ./some_llvm_ext.cc -I /home/user/.local/llvm-15/include -std=c++20 -fno-exceptions -D_GNU_SOURCE
```

Additionally, you need to configure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to your new lib directory. While you can temporarily export a new value, it's worth checking to see if it's blank otherwise you'll have this wonky colon+space thing at the end.

```
# For BASH / ZSH / SH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.local/llvm-15/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

# For FISH
# Note: Some FISH configurations will require `set -gx` depending on the context.
set -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/.local/llvm-15/lib $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Finally, to permanently use this new gem of LLVM, explore how to use `update-alternatives` on Debian based distributions. Likewise read the documentation or explore article tutorials regarding `/etc/ld.so.conf` and any files sourced beneath `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

Last, but most importantly, fix your `PATH` variable to prioritize `/home/user/.local/llvm-15/bin` over all others.

Comment: May also want to point them to [Getting Started with the LLVM System](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-the-source-code-and-building-llvm)